# Is there a script for extracting distinct and not null values in python?

Tags: python, sql, database, distinct

I'm doing data profiling. I want to extract only the distinct values and values that are not null in Python. I have tried creating open lists and appending all new values to the list but that was completely unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you provide more information such as the nature of the data and any attempts you made before and why they 'failed'?

Comment: If you’re looking for distinct values, you might be better of using a set instead of a list, which is more performant and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have your values in a list.

`(b :=set(List)).remove(None)`

you can do `set(List)` to produce a [Mathematical set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) which is basically a list without repeated values. and then `Set.remove(None)` to get rid of null values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
filtered_list = set([value for value in your_list if value != '' and value != None])
```

"set" is a class which is unordered and only accepts unique variables. I do not have enough information on what your null/empty values look like but you can easily set up the conditions as I did in the example above.